# How catch MySQL error in Repo.start_link (Phoenix\Elixir)

Tags: mysql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, repo

When I do **Repo.start_link** with incorrect credential I got state **:ok**

```
{state, pid} = 
      MyApp.Repo.start_link(
        name: nil,
        hostname: hostname,
        username: username,
        password: password,
        database: db_name,
        pool_size: 1
      )
```

state and pid = **{:ok, #PID<0.551.0>}**

But in the logs I got

```
[error] MyXQL.Connection (#PID<0.554.0>) failed to connect: ** (MyXQL.Error) (1045) (ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR) Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

How I can get error message in **{state, pid}**?

Comment: are you saying the error doesn't come up until sometime later?  Like when you attempt to do an operation?  Could you include the exact code that causes the error?

Comment: yes. when trying select data `Repo.one(from d ...`

Comment: You should include the problematic code in your example to help add context.

Comment: the question is why Repo.start_link with incorrect data (wrong password for example) returns :ok. I don't know if this is normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can start another Repo without a name, but you can't access it directly, all operations are sent to the default repository `Myapp.Repo`.

> You can also start repositories without names by explicitly   setting
> the name to nil:
> MyApp.Repo.start_link(name: nil, hostname: "temp.example.com")
> However, once the repository is started, you can't directly interact with
> it, since all operations in `MyApp.Repo` are sent by default to the repository   named `MyApp.Repo`.

Source: https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v3.6.2/lib/ecto/repo.ex#L554